# Grab a word in a complex url by php

Tags: php, regex

Hi I have this url where i want to grab the last word (oath2_access_token) after the equals sign by PHP where the last word can be anything not just oath2_acc..

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/peoplesearch:(facets:(code,buckets:(code,name,count)))?facets=industry,network&facet=industry,12&facet=network,F&oauth2_access_token=oath2_access_token`

Please help to grab the word or atleast provide me the resources where i could learn and do it myself.

Thanks.

Comment: `$_GET['oauth2_access_token']` doesnt work?

Comment: no.. i cant' grab that way cuz oath2_access_token (the value) will be replace then only the url request is made.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/oauth.getaccesstoken.php is this what you're looking for? Do you actually need the access token or whatever is the last string in the url?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### GET

(As others have pointed out) I'm not sure why you can't simply use this...

```
$token = $_GET['oauth2_access_token'];
```

http://php.net/_get

### Regex

Seeing as you have tagged this question with regex...

```
preg_match('/.*=(.*)/', $url, $matches);
$token = $matches[1];
```

- `.*=` => Select everything up to and including the last `=` sign (because `*` is greedy)
- `(.*)` => Select everything after the last `=` sign and capture it

http://php.net/preg_match
http://www.regular-expressions.info/

### Explode

You could also split the url on the `=` sign and take the last index...

```
$url_array = explode('=', $url);
$token = end($url_array);
```

http://php.net/explode
http://php.net/end

Answer (score 3):

You can use explode to get all the values after the equal signs and then just get the last element of the array:

```
<?php
    $url = 'https://api.linkedin.com/v1/peoplesearch:(facets:(code,buckets:(code,name,count)))?facets=industry,network&facet=industry,12&facet=network,F&oauth2_access_token=oath2_access_token';
    $array = explode('=', $url);
    $value = end(array_values($array));
    echo $value;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

`preg_match("/oauth2_access_token\=([a-z0-9_\-]+)/i", $url, $matches);`

I guess this pattern should cover the token, if not you'll need to define the allowed characters between the [] brackets.

Dump $matches to see which index grabs the token.

Answer (score 1):

Either use 
$_GET['oauth2_access_token']

or use [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php). :

```
<?php
$url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/peoplesearch:(facets:(code,buckets:(code,name,count)))?facets=industry,network&facet=industry,12&facet=network,F&oauth2_access_token=oath2_access_token";
$querystring_params = array();
parse_str(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_QUERY), $querystring_params);
echo $querystring_params["oauth2_access_token"];
?>
```